# how many rows/lines/size is a single stored procedure/function limited on mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I will program a stored procedure to execute a very complex business logic. before start, I think there is a very important factor to be cleared. How many rows/lines/size is a single stored procedure/function limited on mysql ? I search using google and stackoverflow and mysql reference manual Limits on InnoDB Tables, but I do not find accurate description.
Any help will/would be appreciated

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on the maximum memory that the process is allowed to use?

Comment: Thanks! My MySql service runs on mini-PC, memory is not question.  SQL code size maybe is a little large, so I care the limitation.

Comment: If you are concerned that your stored procedure is going be too large it is probably an indication of poor design. Rather break it up in smaller stored procedures that will be called by an overarching stored procedure.

Comment: I see, The best design is to divide the centralized code into a number of subprograms. The same applies to MySql.

Comment: I think the limitation is not only restrict by the maximum memory that the process is allowed, but also restrict by some rule of MySql. I just infer the rule is exist, and I wonder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL stores procedures in the `mysql.proc` table, where it uses a `longblob` for the body. This limits the size of your procedure body to the [size of a `longblob`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings), which is 4GB. After that point you receive

> [Error: 1437 SQLSTATE: 42000 (ER_TOO_LONG_BODY)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_too_long_body)
>
> Message: Routine body for '%s' is too long

However, to create a procedure, you have to send a statement to the server that contains the procedure. The size of a packet that you can send to the server is limited by the [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) setting. It's default value is 4MB, which should suffice for any non-trivial procedure. It's maximum value is 1GB, which consequently will be the ultimate limit for your procedure (for now).

Comment: It seems that I don't need to worry about this restriction. Your answer is very helpful to me. ( I am a newbie of MySQL.)